# Unwanted paragraph character in Outlook message

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

When I create a new email in Outlook, I see this unwanted paragraph character on each line. How do I get rid of it?

[image: Outlook screenshot showing unwanted paragraph character]

The arrow points to the character. It cannot be deleted using backspace either.

Comment: Should you find those marks to be handy (as I do), rest assured that the result email will be the same whether or not you've set the marks to be visible. Your recipients will never see them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have formatting marks set to be visible.

Your screenshot matches the following illustration:

[image]

You can hide these formatting marks by the following keyboard shortcut.

### Keyboard shortcut:

> To turn formatting marks on or off, press CTRL+SHIFT+*. You must use
>   the asterisk on the standard keyboard, not on a numeric keypad.

You can also disable it in the message windows using the following description to locate the desired interface button.

### Another Method shortcut:

> In the message window, on the Format Text tab, in the Paragraph group,
>   click Show/Hide.
>
> [image]

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Turn-formatting-marks-on-or-off-b166e811-d762-4f24-8328-d897cdace459)

I should point out that Microsoft Word has an option which enables and disables it's formatting marks.  Microsoft Outlook does not have a similar option, the last message that enabled it, would leave it enabled for the next message.

Comment: How does one type `SHIFT+*`? o.O

Comment: I don't understand your final paragraph. What's the distinction?

Comment: Which paragraph exactly?  My final paragraph indicates, there isn't an entry in the Outlook options, where as there is in Word.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't understand.  It's CTRL+SHIFT+* and it does work.  It does not work if you use the numpad per the instructions.

Comment: Doesn't the latter part of your answer include a _screenshot_ even showing where the option is?

Comment: There is no `*` key that's not on the numpad. There is an `8` key that you can combine with `SHIFT` to get `*`. But I can't press `CTRL+SHIFT+SHIFT+8`. I imagine they meant either `CTRL+*` or `CTRL+SHIFT+8`.

Comment: I think your reading to much into it

Answer (score 5):

Looks like Outlook is set to "Show paragraph marks and other hidden formatting symbols". Look for that same symbol on the Format Text tab of the ribbon (in Outlook 2010 at least) to toggle it on and off.